# On a exchange's "recent trades" list how is a trade designated as either a sale or a buy?

Tags: day-trading, bid-ask

If a maker is making an "ask" and then this is met by a buyer, would that be listed as sale or a buy on the "recent trades" list ?

Specifically I am using the trades list on the Kraken exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Your example would generally be listed as a sell.

Where a buyer buys from the existing sell/ask order that is a sale.

Where a seller sells in to an existing buy/bid order that is a buy.

Comment: Hi,I am getting the feeling it is the other way around . At least on Kraken.

Comment: I mean it's also easy to test.  Put up an order and when it fills look how it's represented in the transaction register.